# Checking if a row exists is very slow in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, query-performance

I have a `product` table and it has an **indexed** column `manufacturer_id`. The table has 30M rows. I want to check if a specific row exists in the table. Queries I used:

```
select exists(select 1 from product where manufacturer_id = '0');

select 1 from product where manufacturer_id = '0' fetch first row only;

select 1 from product where manufacturer_id = '0' limit 1;
```

Each query takes 4 minutes. There are 12M rows with `manufacturer_id = '0'` in the table. However, if I run the same query with `manufacturer_id = '1234567'` (which has 2 rows in the table), it returns the result in 250 milliseconds.

I would expect that checking row existence doesn't take long. Or, am I mistaken and it is normal to take that long given the table volume? If it is not normal, how could I improve the performance?

**Execution plan:**

```
Result  (cost=0.07..0.08 rows=1 width=1) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..914306.95 rows=12306868 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
          Filter: ((manufacturer_id)::text = '0'::text)
          Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.093 ms
Execution Time: 0.036 ms
```

**Create Index statement:** (this is the only index other than the primary key)

```
create index product_manufacturer_id
    on product (manufacturer_id);
```

**manufacturer_id:** `varchar` type and `indexed` column.

**Postgres Version: 12**

Comment: What data type is `manufacturer_id`? If that is an `int` or `bigint` you must compare it with a number. `'1234567'` is a string and thus can't make use of the index, use `where manufacturer_id = 1234567` instead. This would be something that is easily visible in the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze)`

Comment: The column is a `varchar` type and has an `index` already. I edited the question.

Comment: Then please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated of the slow query using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: The plan shows that it takes 0.036 **milli**seconds to run that query - that's not even close to the 4 minutes you mention

Comment: Please show us the complete ddl for the table and indexes. Plus an explain analyze

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, that's totally weird. The same query takes milliseconds now... I tried many times yesterday and it took 3-4 minutes every time. Now, I ran it again and it took 4 mins and 3 secs. I am really confused. I will update the execution plan with the slow one.

Comment: Sounds like PostgreSQL did a vacuum and updated its statistics overnight and could generate better plans the next day.

Answer (score 2):

You want an index on `manufacturer_id`:

```
create index idx_product_manufacturer_id on product(manufacturer_id)
```

You may want additional keys after `manufacturer_id` to support other queries.  But `manufacturer_id` needs to be the first column

Also, you need to be careful about types.  So, you want the comparison to use the same type -- double quotes mean that the comparison is to a string not an integer.  And even if they are both strings, the index may not be used if the collations are not the same.

Without an index, Postgres has to scan the table to find a match.  Apparently, `'1234567'` shows up quickly in whatever order Postgres is scanning.  But `'0'` does not.

An index fixes this problem.  And it will also be helpful for joining to the `manufacturers` table.

Comment: The column is a `varchar` type and has an `index` already.  I edited the question.